# Get next line with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to calculate integral from bash.

I have a file "data.log" which contains:

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
...
xn yn
```

I have created this file with awk.
Now I'd like to manipulate it to get:

```
x2 x1 y2
x3 x2 y3
x4 x3 y4
...
xn xn-1 yn
```

I have tried with:

```
awk 'var=$1; print var; prev=var;' data.log
```

But it didn't work.
Could you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Would it not be better to use something like `octave` to calculate your integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first line, print the current values and the previous value, and on all lines, remember the first field:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print $1, prev, $2 } { prev = $1 }'
```

This produces

```sh
$ for i in {1..4}; do printf "x%d y%d\n" $i $i; done | awk 'NR > 1 { print $1, prev, $2 } { prev = $1 }'
x2 x1 y2
x3 x2 y3
x4 x3 y4
```